# java Constructor in inhertied class giving error

Tags: java

I understand that constructors are not inhertied,

```
error Name has private access in MyClass
error imcompatible types  unexpected return value
```

How should I be setting up the extended class

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.String;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MainClass {    
  public static void main(String[]  args ){

       YourClass xclass = new YourClass ("Sam");
       System.out.println(xclass.getName());
   }
} 

class MyClass {

private String name;

public MyClass(String fn){
       name = fn; }   

 public String getName (){
      return name;} 
}
class YourClass extends MyClass{

   public YourClass(String fn ){
    return name = fn;  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following modifications:

1. You should change the access modifier of the value `name` in `MyClass` from `private` to `protected`. This is because `private` member can only be access from within the same class, so `YourClass` cannot access the variable `name` in `MyClass`.
2. You should add `super(fn);` in the constructor of `YourClass`. This is because if you don't explicitly call the constructor of the super class, the compiler will insert the snippet `super()` by default, which invoke the no-argument constructor, but this constructor does not exist in your code so it will not compile.
3. You should remove `return name = fn;` from the constructor of `YourClass`. This is because constructor should not return anything.

So you should have something like the following:

```
class MyClass {

    protected String name;

    public MyClass(String fn) {
        name = fn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class YourClass extends MyClass {

    public YourClass(String fn) {
        super(fn);
    }
}
```